# "+=" operation not working between types std::complex<double> and __complex__ double

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm using Eigen to perform some matrix manipulations in C++. In it, I have a line schematically of the form

```
MatrixXcd A = MatrixXcd::Zeros(10,10);
A(0,0) += 2.0*1i;
```

Compiling this on my local computer gives no problems. However, compiling it on a different computer using the same CMake file gives the following error:

`error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, -1, -1>, 1>::Scalar {aka std::complex<double>}’ and ‘__complex__ double’)`

so somehow the types `std::comple<double>` and `__complex__ double` are different, and the computer is unable to resolve the difference. Can someone explain to me what these differences are, and how to remove the discrepancy? I could try figuring out how the two computers are configured differently, but that seems like a more difficult problem to get help with online.

Comment: Is this Eigen related, or do you have the same behavior with just `std::complex<double> a{}; a+=2.0*1i;`? (You should provide a [mre] including what compilers and parameters you are using on each computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you add the line

```cpp
using namespace std::complex_literals;
```

at beginning of your main() function.

Also check that probably you want to do `A(0,0) += 2.0 + 1i;` instead of `A(0,0) += 2.0*1i;`

Answer (score 2):

C++ 14 added [new literal syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) to make `a+bi` evaluate to a `std::complex<double>`.

It should suffice to add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) # or 17
```

to your CMakeLists.txt file to make both compilers agree again.

Comment: This line is included in the CMake file, but the errors are still present.

Comment: Then you need to start comparing compiler versions

Comment: You have to add `using namespace std::literals::complex_literals;`